Conversion of TIFF DEM in XYZ
I have this problem (QGIS 3.28): I have created a DEM in another program (RAS Mapper of HEC-RAS), starting from a bathymetry and adding some simple structure on it. I have exported this modified DEM like TIFF file and it's correctly visualized in QGIS (see screenshot). It's a single band raster file.

I need to export it in XYZ file which is the only option I have to add this file in another program to perform an hydraulic modeling.
I have tried all the options I found in other posts: gdal2xyz, raster > conversion > translate, r.out.xyz, but every time something goes wrong:

gdal2xyz: some wrong number appear in the final text file (-9999 in the z column, wich are not
present in my original file);
r.out.xyz: isn't working at all (it blocks after few seconds and I have to close QGIS);
raster > conversion > translate: the interval of z I get in output is in the interval [-0.4;0.4], while should be in [0.31,-7]


NODATA gets mapped to a numeric value, so the first process worked as designed. Each of these issues should be a separate Question.

Add -skipnodata to gdal2xyz to skip NODATA points (height is unknown). You can use -dstnodata  to map -9999 (NODATA) to other value.
